# Iterate an object to find which are the missing numbers and assign a value to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I have a scenario where I need to iterate over an object which is:

```
var rating = {
    "1": "75%",
    "2": "20%",
    "3": "10%"
}
```

and i need to iterate over the rating object and among 1-5 if there are any missing rating i need to assing 0% to it

final output:

```
var rating = {
    "1": "75%",
    "2": "20%",
    "3": "10%",
    "4":"0%",
    "5":"0%"
}
```

i have tried like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    angular.forEach(vm.rating, function(value, key) {
        if (i != parseInt(key)) {
            vm.rating[i.toString()] = "0%";
        }
    });
}
```

but all the values are changed to 0%

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop twice. You know what predefined keys you need, all you should do is check whether or not a key exist and create it if it doesn't.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (!vm.rating.hasOwnProperty(i.toString())) {
            vm.rating[i.toString()] = "0%";
        }
    }
```

By doing forEach within the for loop, you are iterating over all keys and comparing with i, and reassigning all values of keys that do not match with i, to "0%". So by the end of the first i, you already have n-1/n of your keys set to "0%".

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        //angular.forEach(vm.rating, function(value, key) {
            if (!vm.rating[String(i)]) {
                vm.rating[String(i)] = "0%";
            }
        //});
    }
```

Seems you need to fill as dfault value, when doesnt exists

Tks

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```js
function mergeDefaults(rating, defaults) {
  
  for(let key in defaults) {
    if(!defaults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if(!rating.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      rating[key] = defaults[key];
    }
  }
  
  return rating;
}

var rating = {
  "1": "75%",
  "2": "20%",
  "3": "10%"
}
var defaults = {
  "1": "75%",
  "2": "20%",
  "3": "10%",
  "4":"0%",
  "5":"0%"
}

mergeDefaults(rating, defaults);
console.log(rating);
```

## ES Next Version:

```
var data = Object.assign({}, defaults, rating);
```

## [Angular 1.*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
var data = angular.extend({}, defaults, rating);
```